# Using recursion to compute a 2d pyramid arrays weight

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on some homework about recursion and ive been struggling to understand how to do a few parts of the homework.

Part of the assignment we have to calculate the weight supported at each object. This is the weight of the object itself, plus half of the supported weight of the objects above it.

```
   A

  B C

 D E F

G H I J
```

So A is itself

B is itself + half of A

C is itself + half of A

E is itself + half of B + half of C

These are some of the tests my method should pass

```
public void RecursionTestComputePyramidWeightsInputTest() {
    double [][] weights = {{}};
    double [][] weights1 = {
            { 51.18 },
            { 55.90, 131.25 },
            { 69.05, 133.66, 132.82 },
            { 53.43, 139.61, 134.06, 121.63 }
    };

    Assert.assertEquals("ComputePyramidWeights must be able to handle an empty array", 0.0, Recursion.computePyramidWeights(weights, 0, 0), 0.001);
    Assert.assertEquals("ComputePyramidWeights must be able to handle negative row values", 0.0, Recursion.computePyramidWeights(weights, -1, 0), 0.001);
    Assert.assertEquals("ComputePyramidWeights must be able to handle negative col values", 0.0, Recursion.computePyramidWeights(weights, 0, -1), 0.001);
    Assert.assertEquals("ComputePyramidWeights must be able to handle invalid column", 0.0, Recursion.computePyramidWeights(weights1, 0, 3), 0.001);
    Assert.assertEquals("ComputePyramidWeights must be able to handle invalid row", 0.0, Recursion.computePyramidWeights(weights1, 4, 0), 0.001);
}

@org.junit.Test
public void RecursionTestComputePyramidWeightsTest() {
    double weights[][] = {
                       { 51.18 },
                    { 55.90, 131.25 },
                { 69.05, 133.66, 132.82 },
            { 53.43, 139.61, 134.06, 121.63 }
    };

    Assert.assertEquals("ComputePyramidWeights must be able to handle an array with a single row and col", 51.18, Recursion.computePyramidWeights(weights, 0, 0), 0.001);
    Assert.assertEquals("ComputePyramidWeights must be able to handle an array with multiple rows and one col", 108.327, Recursion.computePyramidWeights(weights, 3, 0), 0.001);
    Assert.assertEquals("ComputePyramidWeights must be able to handle an array with multiple cols and rows", 227.25, Recursion.computePyramidWeights(weights, 3, 3), 0.001);
}
```

The tests that I am struggling with are the 4th on the first test(must be able to handle invalid row), and the 3rd on the 2nd test(must be able to handle an array with multiple cols and rows)

my code so far

```
public static double computePyramidWeights(double[][] weights, int row, int column){
    if(row < 0 || column < 0 || column > weights[row].length-1){ // ive also tried row > weights[columns].length-1 and it does what i need it to but for some reason when i use both one stops working.
        return 0.0;
    }
    else if (row == 0 && column == 0){
        return weights[0][0];
    }else if (row == 0 || column == 0){
        return weights[row][column] + .5 *(computePyramidWeights(weights, row-1, column)) + .5 * (computePyramidWeights(weights, row, column-1));
    }
    else return 5; // this is a placeholder so i could run the tests, this is where i would need my recursive call, but i really dont know how to even go about this one.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Added condition `row > weights.length - 1`.

> This is the weight of the object itself, plus half of the supported weight of the objects above it.

From your definition, it is not clear how to compute the weight of middle elements.

I assumed that it is the sum of current element + half of the weight of the element at `weights[row - 1][column - 1]` as that was producing the expected output.

But for the first column, I guess you have to get current element + half the weight of the element at `weights[row - 1][0]`  (again based on test output)

I removed the case for `row = 0` as the first row can only have one element and hence that would be covered by the first `else if` case.

Here's the one that passes all your tests

```
public static double computePyramidWeights(double[][] weights, int row, int column) {
   if(row < 0 || column < 0 || row > weights.length - 1 || column > weights[row].length-1){ 
       return 0.0;
    }
    else if (row == 0 && column == 0){
        return weights[0][0];
    } else if (column == 0) {
            return weights[row][column]
                    + .5 *(computePyramidWeights(weights, row - 1, column));
    }

   return weights[row][column]
            + .5 *(computePyramidWeights(weights, row - 1, column - 1));

}
```

Comment: You're right i did leave the information for the middle elements out I edited my post to account for that, Also thank you very much for your answer Im able to see now where i went wrong.

Comment: for `H` -> do we need to take half of `D` and `E`? If yes, you need to add one more line `+ .5 *(computePyramidWeights(weights, row - 1, column))`

Comment: getting h is a bit complicated but it goes like (((((a/2)+b)/2)+d)/2) this is half of D then we would get E which is ((((a/2)+b)/2) + (((a/2)+c)/2)) + e / 2. This is our half of E now we can add the half of E + half of D + all of H.